# Read HDF5 file within .net

Tags: hdf5, hdf, hdf5dotnet

I am trying to read a file with [HDF5DotNet.dll](http://hdf5.net/) but I am getting the following error:

```
1. Solution exception:H5F.open
File "recorder.h5"  failed to open with status -1
```

I have been able to open the file with HDFView so I am pretty sure the file is not corrupted.
The file is created from an FEA software that it is using "HDF5 library version: 1.10.1".

I have attached the file in case someone wants to try to help

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SAKkZf0VGHRfbdPKabyiEPzpEXie4VzC/view?usp=sharing

**Code that I have used**

```
import HDF5DotNet

from HDF5DotNet import *

import System
from System import Array, Double, Int64

print('\nInitializing HDF5 library\n')
status = H5.Open()
print('HDF5 ', H5.Version.Major, '.', H5.Version.Minor, '.', H5.Version.Release)

h5file = H5F.open('recorder.hdf5', H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY)
H5F.close(h5file)
print '\nShutting down HDF5 library\n'
status = H5.Close()
```

Comment: I use Python to access HDF5 FEA data  (pytables and h5py). I was able to open the file and read the node names with both packages. Do you know if HDF5DotNet is compatible with HDF5 version 1.10.1? You may need to ask on **The HDF Group Forums**.  (As I understand, they are the creators of HDF5DotNet)

Comment: I remember reading a blog post about this from The HDF5 Group. Based on a quick read, I suspect HDF5.Net does not support any recent HDF5 versions. In 2016 they announced HDF.PInvoke as a replacement. See this post for details and download info: [HDF5 and .NET](https://www.hdfgroup.org/2016/01/hdf5-net-one-step-back-two-steps-forward/)

Comment: thanks kcw78.
I am not sure I'll be able to follow with HDF.PInvokes but it is helpful.
Is there an easy way to get a .dll that works with my file?
I have wrote in HDF Group forum and I hope they will help as well.

Comment: I'm not a .NET guy, so that's the limit of my knowledge. Sorry. The HDF team is your best bet if you don't get an answer on SO.

Comment: thanks anyway. Really appreciate!